# cannot find module 'gulp-live-server' -> heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm working with node and heroku for the first time but I'm running into an issue when trying to view my app after deployment. I keep getting the error Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-live-server'.

I've already set the NODE_PATH and NODE_ENV but I still get the missing module error. I'm not sure what else the issue might be. The gulp-live-server module is in my node_modules folder which is in the root of my application.

Thanks in advance for your help! I really appreciate it.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');
var db = require('./models/');
var pg = require('pg');
var client = new pg.Client(config.host);
var live = require('gulp-live-server');

app.use(require(live));

// allow serving of static files (ie in public)
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//You can use whatever templating engine you would like
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');

//Create routes
require('./routes')(app);

//Connect to Postgres DB & sync models
db.sequelize
 .sync()
 .then(function () {
    // Start server
    app.listen(config.port);
    console.error("connected to db");
    console.error(config.port);
  }, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

error log:

```
  2016-09-11T01:49:51.923465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from        crashed to starting
  2016-09-11T01:49:54.416652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with  command `node server.js`
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.172996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.113742+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.113765+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.113766+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.113767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
  2016-09-11T01:49:57.113781+00:00 app[web.1]:     at      Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your dependencies in your `package.json` file.

If you installed `gulp-live-server` in your local instance with something like `npm install gulp-live-server`, that won't save the dependency in your `package.json` file.

Installing it with `npm install --save gulp-live-server` will add the dependency to your `package.json`. You can then deploy with the resulting `package.json`.